# Turning a verse into a syllogism to get its meaning

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about how to turn a particular verse or two into a syllogism. Where should I post that question? 
Thx very much

Comment: We have a site for [English language usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).  Alternatively you could discuss it  in chat on this site.

Comment: While I'm not sure ELL would be the best option either, I think there *are* better options than Christianity.SE: If you are focusing on understanding syllogisms and how to parse text into them, then I think Philosophy.SE is the best bet. If you are focusing on the underlying meaning of a particular biblical  text, then Hermeneutics.SE would be better.

Comment: er, that should have been ELU, not ELL (which is yet another SE site).

Comment: Of course, you _can't_ turn a verse or two into a syllogism. You can only turn them into the _premises_ (or the conclusion) of a syllogism....